Do uncountable coproducts of probability measures exist uniquely?
Is there such a thing as a coproduct of an uncountable number of probability measures?  Afaik this is true in the countable case. In the case of products, the uncountable product of totally finite measures is uniquely defined. But Is this the case for coproducts as well?
For the record, what I have in mind as the co-product of two probability measure spaces $(\mu, \Sigma, X)$ and $(\mu', \Sigma', X')$ in the finite case is defined to be the measure $(\mu \sqcup \mu', \Sigma \sqcup \Sigma', X \sqcup X')$ such that
$$(\mu \sqcup \mu')(A \sqcup A') = \frac{\mu(A) + \mu'(A')}{2}$$
with $A \in \Sigma$ and $A' \in \Sigma'$
It seems like the proof should be a simple application of zorns lemma, but the existence of a unique coproduct measure seems very unlikely to me because of the existence of non measurable subsets of the reals. Technically the existence of such subsets may not contradict the existence of uncountable coproducts, but if we could construct an uncountable coproduct we could define a measure on any non measurable subset of the reals, it just would have to have nothing to do with the lebesgue measure.
The way we would construct such a measure on a non-measurable set $S$ is just to associate to each point $x \in S$ a measure $\mu_x$ with a $\sigma$-algebra consisting of only $x$ itself and the empty set, then set $\mu_x(x) = 1$ and $\mu_x(\varnothing) = 0$. Then we could just take $\bigsqcup_{x \in S} \mu_x$ as the measure on $S$.
Notably, it does seem like the construction of the uncountable coproduct measure might depend on the axiom of choice, but so does the existence of non-measurable sets afaik.
In particular, this answer on mathoverflow seems to indicate that yes, this construction should exist. But the 'weirdness' of such objects seems to not be addressed for the uncountable case.
So do these measures exist, or not?

The construction you've described in the finite case is not a coproduct; where would the division by $2$ come from? To be precise, it can't be a coproduct because it's not associative; $(\mu_1 \sqcup \mu_2) \sqcup \mu_3$ is a different measure from $\mu_1 \sqcup (\mu_2 \sqcup \mu_3)$, and neither of them is the measure where you divide the sum of the measures by $3$.
Here is what strikes me as a straightforward and unproblematic construction of a "coproduct" (I have not checked if this is technically a coproduct) of an arbitrary collection of measures, rather than probability measures. Given an arbitrary collection of measure spaces $(X_i, \Sigma_i, \mu_i)$ we can construct the measure space whose

sample space is $\bigsqcup_i X_i$,
$\sigma$-algebra is generated by the images of each of the $\sigma$-algebras $\Sigma_i$ (what you wrote here is not correct even in the finite case; the disjoint union of $\sigma$-algebras is not a $\sigma$-algebra) (edit: this may not be the right $\sigma$-algebra), and
measure is defined by the property that it restricts to $\mu_i$ on $\Sigma_i$.

The axiom of choice is not used in any way, and this is not in any way in tension with the existence of non-measurable subsets of the reals. If you apply this construction to $\mathbb{R}$ regarded as an uncountable disjoint union of points you just get counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (on the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra, but it extends to the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets), which unproblematically exists and has nothing to do with Lebesgue measure.
This construction, of course, does not produce probability measures as output when given probability measures as input. It seems to me that in order to do this you need to prescribe, as an additional piece of data, a probability measure on the index set $I$ itself so that you can average the measures $\mu_i$ with respect to this index measure. If $I$ is finite it's natural to take this measure to be normalized counting measure but in general you'd need to make a real choice here. Which means $I$ itself needs to be a probability space, and then I'm not sure what the right definition should be anymore.

I see, perhaps I should not have used the word 'coproduct' then and linked to that mathoverflow post. I should have been more explicit. The heart of my question is the uncountable extension of the concept of taking the measures $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_n$  over $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ to the measure $(\sum_i \mu_i) / (\sum_i \mu_i(X_i))$. For an infinite countable sequence this should converge. Is it possible that converges uniquely? Can the least upper bound of the sum change based on order? In other words, choice has to be made, but its not clear to me if that choice matters

@William: the result of taking that limit is not a probability measure. If you perform that limiting construction on $\mathbb{N}$ regarded as a countable disjoint union of singletons you get natural density (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), which is not countably additive. I think, again, that you have to pick a probability measure on the index set $I$.
